# Page not Scrolling to top onClick of a react-router-dom Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a component that has a react-router-dom Link inside a Modal (react-bootstrap).
I am passing state while navigating to another page.

```js
class EditCook extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <Modal>
    <Modal.Body>
     <Link to=`/edit-cook/${nextCookId}` onClick={() => closesModal()}>Next Cook</Link>
    </Modal.Body>
  </Modal>
  );
 }
}
```

I have written only the code about the problem I am having.
I already have a ScrollToTop component in my App.js as suggested by [react-router-dom docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration)

Any help will be welcome!

Please let me know if more details are required.

My app.js

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <Router>
       <ScrollToTop />        //<---------------as explained in react router docs
       <Switch>
         <Route to='/edit-cook/:cookid' component={EditCook}/>

         ....                 // <---------------other routes
       </Switch>
     </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How is your `App.js` ?

Comment: @CorentindeMaupeou I have updated the question with the skeleton of my App.js

Comment: Your route is `/edit-cook` not `/edit-cook/:yourcookieid`, it's normal if it not works. 
Your have this tutorial for make that : https://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/route-params

Comment: @CorentindeMaupeou, my route is having :cookid I have just corrected it in the question

Comment: Are you getting your `nextCookId ` value with props ?

Comment: @CorentindeMaupeou yes thats right.

Comment: With this code, try to delete your `onClick` function, it's maybe that. And what's the code about `EditCook` file ?